# Undefined Property in Class Inheritance?

Tags: php

I just started to learn OOP PHP, and i've been done some exercises, and i got a problem with inheritance classes that return these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: HtmlEmailer::$recipients in C:\xampp\htdocs\class.htmlemailer.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\class.htmlemailer.php on line 10
```

why is Undefined Property? i did define it in emailer.test.php...

i did read 3x the same chapter of my book, inspect each part of code and i didn't realize where the error is.

there is my code: class.emailer.php

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Emailer
{
    private $sender;
    private $recipients;
    private $subject;
    private $body;

    function __construct($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->recipients = array();
    }

    public function addRecipients($recipients)
    {
        array_push($this->recipients, $recipients);
    }

    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient)
        {
            $result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body, "From: ".$this->sender."\r\n");
            if ($result)
            {
                echo "Email successfully sent to ".$recipient;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

class.htmlemailer.php

```
<?php
/**
* htmlemailer extends emailer
*/

class HtmlEmailer extends Emailer
{
    public function sendHTMLEmail()
    {
        foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient)
        {
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: {$this->sender}' . "\r\n";

            $result = mail($recipient, $this->subject, $this->body, $headers);
            if ($result)
            {
                echo "HTML mail successfully sent to ".$recipient." ! <br />";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

emailer.test.php

```
<html>

<?php 
/**
 * tests
 */
include_once('class.emailer.php');
include_once('class.htmlemailer.php');

$emailerobject = new HtmlEmailer('some@emaildotcom');
$emailerobject->addRecipients('user@emaildotcom');
$emailerobject->setSubject('Some Subject');
$emailerobject->setBody('Some body message');
$emailerobject->sendHTMLEmail();

?>

</html>
```

Comment: problem solved. thanks both rray and mapek. ps.: im reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php right now.

Comment: I came across this issue also, googling a solution brought me here which in turn solved the issue (thanks rray, mapek and wdarking) and brought to light another small issue: in the file "class.htmlemailer.php" below the line of $emailerobject->setbody('some body mesage'); you need to add $emailerobject->sendEmail(); or upon executing the code you will be shown a blank white page with no email being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inheritance private property only protecteds or publics. If you want that descents class inheritance  change `private` by `protected`, so they will be acessible.

```
class Emailer
{
    protected $sender;
    protected $recipients;
    protected $subject;
    protected $body;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

```
private $recipients;
```

to

```
protected $recipients;
```

to make the property accessible in subclasses.

Please read the php doc about [visibility in PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).